# Phusion passenger - glibc not found

Tags: apache, ruby-on-rails-3.2, passenger

I have rvm and installed ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.9

I have installed phusion passenger 4.0.25.

sh-3.2# gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.5.2

when I start the httpd service. It gives me the following error-

**Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 994 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /var/www/.rvm/src/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails329/gems/passenger-4.0.25/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so into server: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by /var/www/.rvm/src/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails329/gems/passenger-4.0.25/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so)**

Comment: How did you install Phusion Passenger?

Comment: I installed ruby using rvm and them rails using gem install. Then i ran gem install passenger and then "passenger-install-apache2-module"

Comment: It looks like there is something wrong with your compiler - for some reason it links against the wrong libstdc++ version. There's nothing Passenger can do about that. I'm not sure what exactly is wrong though.